# install both Python and R in a conda environment

Tags: python, r, conda, virtual-environment

I have a conda environment configured for a Python3.6 project. There is a completely unrelated project which requires me to update my system's (base) R version. However, that would break my python project which happens to use some R functionality as well, which would break with the new version of R.

- can I use the same conda environment for both Python and R? How would I modify my current python environment to do that?
- can I integrate my *existing* (old) R version in the conda environment, and make room on my base system for the new R version?

There was a lot of fidgeting getting the old R version to work because of dependency clashes, so I'd rather not do a ""clean"" reinstall into the conda environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this:

```
$ conda create --name env_name_py37r36 python=3.7 R=3.6 -y
```

https://rc.partners.org/kb/article/3688

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for R>=4.0. However, this fixed it for me: `conda config --add channels conda-forge` as recommended for a different problem here: https://www.biostars.org/p/498049/